# UIScrollView: zoom only some views

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I do have a UIScrollView with a single customContentView as subview. This is returned as the viewForZoomingInScrollView: . But this way, every subview of my customContentView is zoomed: I would like to have some zoomed, others not (e.g. labels), but of course the relative position should remain. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What stops you from using two Scrollview subviews - One that contains components that can be zoomed & other contains components that cannot be zoomed?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but do the positions relative to each other stay correct then between views that are zoomed and those that are not? E.g. a rectangle view with a label next to it: the rectangle should zoom, the label shouldn't but the label should always stay next to the rectangle.

Comment: I just tested it - no, they don't unfortunately, so that's no solution to my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need apply inverse scale transform to the label as below,

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    sampleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1/scrollView.zoomScale, y: 1/scrollView.zoomScale)
}
```

Before Zoom,

[image: BeforeZoom]

After Zoom,
[image: After Zoom]

Comment: great, awesome, perfect!