# How to zoom image without zooming subviews of an image? swift ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I added `UIImageView` which is subview of `UIScrollView`. Then I added `UIButton` is subview of `UIImageView`. When I zoom `UIImageView` then `UIButton` is also perform zooming. I want only zoom `UIImageView` not `UIButton`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't make button subview of UIImageView instead make it subview of scrollview

Comment: Hello Vikky, Thanks for quick reply but this approach will not solve my problem because i want a way that my button will not zoom as well as its position on image will remain same.

Comment: You have to update buttons  frame when you are zooming IN or zooming OUT. You can do it in scrollViewDidZoom delegate method.Only change buttons width and height not x,y.I have not tried this but i thing it should work.

Comment: See this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079806/uiscrollview-zoom-only-some-views

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIButton` is subview of `UIImageView`, it will pan/zoom when you zoom/pan `UIImageView`. To solve your problem, make it subview of some other view, perhaps `UIScrollView` in your case.

Comment: Hello Zee,Thanks for quick reply but this approach will not solve my problem because i want a way that my button will not zoom as well as its position on image will remain same.

Comment: Then add your button to the superview (parent) of UIScrollView, anything under UIScrollView will be scrolled.

Comment: Yes i tried this but button position on image do not remain same. I don't want to change button position on image.

Comment: I may not be understanding your scenario correctly. May be you should add an other UIView under UIScrollView, having same dimensions as your UIImageView, bring this new view to front, add UIButton to this view. set new view to transparent color and disabled touch events on this new view or forward events back to UIImageView, so that you user can pan/zoom the UIImageView. Hope it helps.